# Build Docker Image File of Spring Boot Application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker, docker-toolbox, dockerfile-maven-plugin

I am trying to build a docker image for my spring boot maven project by using dockerfile-maven-plugin. I am using Docker Tool Box on windows 7 and it is running fine.

I am getting Below Error:

> Failed to load Google application default credentials
>   java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not
>   available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine.
>   Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
>   must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

**Pom.XML Build**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
          <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.10</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>default</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
             <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
            <repository>${project.artifactId}</repository>
            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
            <buildArgs>
              <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
            </buildArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
          </executions>
             <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>D:\spring\MicroServiceOutput</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am not able to get that why we need google default credential to build a local image.Please help me out as I am new to Docker World.

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804297/what-docker-base-image-from-for-java-spring-boot/42393001#42393001) may help

Comment: It is not creating Docker file...

Comment: I've updated the answer with some detail, mvn clean install fabric8:build

Comment: Getting ' Cannot include project artifact:' Error..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that's a [bug](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/issues/268), by default the plugin set googleContainerRegistryEnabled flag to true, so you have to change that flag to false, try this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>prefix</docker.image.prefix>
    <docker.image.name>${project.artifactId}</docker.image.name>
    <docker.image.tag>${project.version}</docker.image.tag>
    <docker.file>Dockerfile</docker.file>
</properties>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <googleContainerRegistryEnabled>false</googleContainerRegistryEnabled>
                <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${docker.image.name}</repository>
                <tag>${docker.image.tag}</tag>
                <dockerfile>${docker.file}</dockerfile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>tag</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>push</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>push</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```